# Firebase Scheduled Function Delay When Doing Two Tasks With Same Time Interval

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on an auction application with **Cloud Firestore** as **database**. When a user uploads a post it has three main properties **status**, **startsAt**, **endsAT**. Initially the status will be **pending**. And then I have written a **cloud scheduled functions** with 1 minute interval to check and update the status to **live** when it reaches the **startAt** time and to update the status to **completed** when it reaches the **endsAt** time.

Now my problem is the second step, which is update **status** to **completed** always updates 1 minute late. But when I remove one operation the update to **live** part it works fine. This issue occurs only when I try to do two tasks with the same time interval.

Below is my code.

```
import { onSchedule } from "firebase-functions/v2/scheduler";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase-admin/firestore";
import { AUCTION_STATUS, COLLECTION_NAME } from "../../enums";
import { IAuctionPost } from "../../interfaces";
import * as logger from "firebase-functions/logger";

export const updateStatusToLive = onSchedule("every 1 minutes", async () => {
  try {
    const currentTime = new Date();
    currentTime.setSeconds(0); // remove seconds

    const pendingPostsSnapshot = await getFirestore()
      .collection(COLLECTION_NAME.POSTS)
      .where("status", "==", AUCTION_STATUS.PENDING)
      .get();

    const updatePromises = pendingPostsSnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
      const postData = doc.data() as IAuctionPost;
      const startTime = postData.startsAt.toDate();
      startTime.setSeconds(0); // remove seconds
      logger.log("start time", startTime);
      logger.log("current time", currentTime);

      // Check if the current time is equal to or after the start date
      if (currentTime.valueOf() >= startTime.valueOf()) {
        logger.info("item found");
        return doc.ref.update({ status: AUCTION_STATUS.LIVE });
      }
      // If no update is made, return null
      return null;
    });

    // Wait for all update operations to complete
    await Promise.all(updatePromises);
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error("could not update to LIVE status", error);
  }
});

export const updateStatusToCompleted = onSchedule(
  "every 1 minutes",
  async () => {
    try {
      const currentTime = new Date();
      currentTime.setSeconds(0); // remove seconds

      const pendingPostsSnapshot = await getFirestore()
        .collection(COLLECTION_NAME.POSTS)
        .where("status", "==", AUCTION_STATUS.LIVE)
        .get();

      const updatePromises = pendingPostsSnapshot.docs.map(async (doc) => {
        const postData = doc.data() as IAuctionPost;
        const endTime = postData.endsAT.toDate();
        endTime.setSeconds(0); // remove seconds
        logger.log("end time", endTime);
        logger.log("current time", currentTime);

        // Check if the current time is equal to or after the start date
        if (currentTime.valueOf() >= endTime.valueOf()) {
          logger.info("item found");
          return doc.ref.update({ status: AUCTION_STATUS.COMPLETED });
        }
        // If no update is made, return null
        return null;
      });

      // Wait for all update operations to complete
      await Promise.all(updatePromises);
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle any potential errors here
      logger.error("could not update to COMPLETE status", error);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: I'm not clear as to what you mean by " This issue occurs only when I try to do two tasks with the same time interval." and by "remove one operation" ?

Comment: So my requirement is I want two functions to run every one minute. The first one will get all the documents where status equals to pending and check the current time with start time if it is equal or passed it will update the status to live. The second function will get all the documents with the status of live and check current time with end time if the time is equal or passed it will update it to completed. The problem here is if I deploy anyone of the above function it works fine. But when I deploy both the function either one of the function delays 1 minute.

Comment: To explain you more its like this lets say we have a post with end time at 11:30Pm and status as live and the current time is 11:30Pm. Now the expected behavior is the status should be updates as completed. If I deploy only one function it works fine. But when I deploy both the function it updates the status to completed at 11:31